# HTML Tables: Spacing Hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, href, html-table

I'm in need of assistance, I'm stuck on the most *trivial* thing! My class assignment is to make a website, I've got the basic layout on my template done, but am stuck on hyperlink tables.

I can't get the hyperlinks to have a gap between each table setting! Instead the outcome is all the words (spaced), but all the spaces are underlined!

(Note words are underlined) Kinda_Like_This

This is my code:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    table {position:relative; top:15px;left:15px; letter-spacing:5px;}
bottomTable {position:relative; top:100px;left:16px;}

<table>
    <td><a href="http://www.foxnews.com">  Foxnews </a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.pbs.org">PBS </a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.bing.com"> Bing </a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.google.com"> Google </a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.blogger.com"> Blogger </a></td>
```

I've been trying it at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That link takes us to a background-image 'tutorial'.

Comment: @BeatAlex Yep, people should test & post using http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: BeatAlex, this is what I used to display my code. How it will appear online (sorry I failed to mention that earlier). I used jsbin.com, but it was buggy on my Mac. I'm definitely going to look into these answers right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `padding` instead of `letter-spacing` and you didn't end the style tag properly

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FEWZP/)

### css

```
table {        
    top:15px;
    left:15px;     
  }

td{
padding:10px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<table>
    <td><a href="http://www.foxnews.com">  Foxnews </a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.pbs.org">PBS </a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.bing.com"> Bing </a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.google.com"> Google </a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.blogger.com"> Blogger </a></td>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't understand what padding was, so simple! :) Thank you Thirumalai murugar for this simple explanation!

Comment: @HowbeitGirl Welcome. I hope you have understand the concept now, table is the old method you could do this by `ul` to achieve this, you could give an up-vote for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the spaces *outside* the anchors
like this:

```
<td> <a href="http://www.foxnews.com">Foxnews</a> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding for making distance between hyperlinks and text-decoration: none to get rid if underlines

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
}

table {
position:relative; 
border: 1px solid red; 
top: 10px; 
left: 10px;
}

td {
padding: 10px;
}

bottomTable {
position:relative;
top:100px;
left:16px;
}
```